# php Restler Routes

Tags: php, routes, restler

I am using Restler 2.0  and I'm trying to add a new route based on the CRUD example

```
$o['GET']['author/:name/:email']=array (
  'class_name' => 'Author',
  'method_name' => 'getLogin',
  'arguments' => 
  array (
    'name'  => 0,
    'email' => 1,
  ),
  'defaults' => 
  array (
    0 => NULL,
    1 => NULL,
  ),
  'metadata' => 
  array (
  ),
  'method_flag' => 0,
);
```

when I make the url call in the browser `http://[host]/author/[name to pull]/[email to pull]`

I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}
```

my author code has been updated with the following method

```
function getLogin($name=NULL,$email=NULL) {
    print "in author, getting login";
    return $this->dp->getLogin($name,$email);
}
```

I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

### Luracast Restler Auto Routing

Firstly, `routes.php` is auto generated when you run Restler in production mode

```
$r = new Restler(TRUE);
```

which will be overwritten when we call

```
$r->refreshCache();
```

or run it in debug mode, so it should not be hand coded.

**Restler 2.0** is using *auto mapping* which is better explained in the updated [CRUD Example](http://help.luracast.com/restler/examples/_006_crud/readme.html).

Corrected version of your method should be

```
function get($name=NULL,$email=NULL) {
    print "in author, getting login";
    return $this->dp->getLogin($name,$email);
}
```

which will map to

```
GET /author/:email/:password
```

where as your method is currently mapping to

```
GET /author/login/:email/:password
```

---

### Luracast Restler Custom Routing

Also note that you can use PHPDoc comment to create custom mappings and you can add more than one. For example

```
/*
* @url GET /custom/mapping/:name/:email
* @url GET /another/:name/:email
*/
function get($name=NULL,$email=NULL) {
    print "in author, getting login";
    return $this->dp->getLogin($name,$email);
}
```

this will create the following routes, and disable auto routing for that method.

```
GET /author/custom/mapping/:email/:password
GET /author/another/:email/:password
```

Comment: I understand now.  That's actually what I wanted.  the CRUD example downloaded had a routes.php provided with the example (example 06).  I assume this was to provide specific mapping.  Thanks!

Comment: @CavelleBenjamin You are right, presence of routes.php with out explanation creates confusion, I will remove it in the next update.

Comment: Please don't remove unless there will be a simpler way of adding specific routes.  app specific routes.php file is powerful and great.  Thanks!

Comment: @CavelleBenjamin I'm not removing the feature, just the file which is not used in development mode. Easy way to add custom routes is by adding a PHPDoc comment at the top of your method like `@url GET /my/custom/url` I'm updating my answer above to include an example